# Trying to call my model in Tkinter but it's not waiting until the button is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

This is what I tried and ended up getting. I am trying to call my model in Tkinter but it's not waiting until the button is clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
var = tk.IntVar()

root = tk.Tk()
class model():
    if var == 1:
        os.system('python script.py')

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=lambda: var.set(1))
button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

print("waiting...")
button.wait_variable(var)
print("done waiting.")
```

Result of the code above:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    var = tk.IntVar()
  File "C:\Users\laksh\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 529, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Users\laksh\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 335, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'```
````

Answer (score 3):

The tk.Tk() call starts the tcl interpreter, so no tk objects can be created before you call it. So move tk.Tk() call above the tk.IntVar() call.

```
root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that you're not importing the `Tk` module. Try also importing Tk by adding this line.

```py
From Tkinter import *
```

Also, the module is called Tk, so you'll want to capitalize the `T` in `tk`

Hope this helped!

Comment: Using the `from tkinter import *` wildcard import is actually against the official python style guide (PEP8). We recommend the `import tkinter as tk` style, which means you call it with `tk.Tk()`.